# Custom ColorableItems in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, languageservice

I am working on a LanguageService for Visual Studio and am having issues with custom colors in Visual Studio 2013.  I recently moved from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013, and now whenever I set `RequestStockColors` to `false`, I lose all syntax highlighting.

My LanguageService implements `GetColorableItem` and `GetItemCount`.  I am using 9 custom colors.  When I debug my language service, I have noticed that `GetColorableItem` is called a handful of times, but `GetItemCount` never gets hit.

I am using the following command-line arguments when I debug through Visual Studio:

`/ranu /rootsuffix Exp`

**Update:** I changed the name of the first 5 colors (the ones that overlap with the standard token colors) to match the standard names (e.g. "Keyword", "Identifier", etc.) and those colors now show, but none of my extra color types show up.  In addition, I never see any of them appear in the Fonts and Colors configuration in Visual Studio.  How do I get them to be installed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to create an instance of `ClassificationFormatDefinition` for each of my custom colors and export them as a `EditorFormatDefinition` type.  Once I did this, they showed up in the Fonts and Colors page and also showed up in syntax highlighting.

For each color beyond the default 6, I added a class definition as follows:

```cs
[Export(typeof(EditorFormatDefinition))]
[ClassificationType(ClassificationTypeNames = "<name of color>")]
[Name("<name of color>")]
[UserVisible(true)]
[Order(Before = Priority.Default)]
internal sealed class ExampleColor: ClassificationFormatDefinition
{
    public ExampleColor()
    {
        this.DisplayName = "<name of color>";
        this.ForegroundColor = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 128, 128);
    }
}
```

I am still seeing no hits on my `GetItemCount()` method, however.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into a similar issue where my custom ColorableItems weren't showing up in my syntax highlighting. I was able fix this by clearing the font and color cache.

I temporarily included the following in my Initialize method of my vs package:

```
IVsFontAndColorCacheManager mgr = this.GetService(typeof(SVsFontAndColorCacheManager)) as IVsFontAndColorCacheManager;
mgr.ClearAllCaches();
```

This fixed things for me. This fix shouldn't require including the 6 default values or require any additional ClassificationFormatDefinition classes.

NOTE: Worth mentioning that I also never see GetItemCount() called, but clearing the cache fixed the primary issue.

Credit: Also some credit to a comment by Ed Dore on this thread http://www.databaseforum.info/8/1217583.aspx that helped me find my fix.